# is has_one and has_many equivalent to has_one and belongs_to_many in ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby, activerecord, associations

In Rails (3.2) what is the correct approach to implement the equivalent of County `belongs_to_many` Zipcodes and a Zipcode `has_one` County, given there is no association called belongs_to_many ?

Both models have a `county_code`, which is unique in County, and which in Zipcode identifies all the zipcodes in that county. (This example assumes zipcodes never span counties)

Using has_one and belongs_to does not provide a method to access all zipcodes in a county:

```
class Zipcode < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :county, foreign_key: "county_code", primary_key: "county_code"
end

class County < ActiveRecord::Base
     # belongs_to_many would be correct, if such a thing existed
  belongs_to :zipcode, foreign_key: "county_code", primary_key: "county_code"
end

# not defined because of the belongs_to
all_zipcodes_in_in_1st_county = County.first.zipcodes
```

On the other hand, using has_one plus has_many *seems* to do the trick:

```
class Zipcode < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :county, foreign_key: "county_code", primary_key: "county_code"
end

class County < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :zipcodes, foreign_key: "county_code", primary_key: "county_code"
end
```

Is omitting some form of belongs_to breaking something I'm not testing for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you would do an inverse relationship using `belongs_to` instead of `has_one` (e.g. `Zipcode` would use `belongs_to` instead of `has_one`). The difference between the two is that `belongs_to` means the underlying table has a foreign key field that points to another table, where `has_one` means it's the related table that has the foreign key pointing back to the current table.

Since you have `county_code` as a field on both tables (and thus have to explicitly declare which fields are to be used as the FK and PK) you can effectively use `has_one` or `belongs_to` interchangeably and it's more a matter of what feels semantically correct.